# Endless or Inescapable SMART Failure Predicted on Hard Disk

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot

Here is the situation:
Whenever I start the laptop it says "
Smart Hard Disk Error
 The SMART hard disk check has detected an imminent failure. To ensure not data loss. please backup the content immediately and run the Hard Disk Test in System Diagnostics.
Hard Disk 1 (301)
F2 System Diagnostics
Enter - Continue Startup
For more information, please visit: www.hp.com/go/techcenter/startup
"

I try system diagnostics and it tells me the memory is 100% ok, but the quick test fails at 4%. After running the diagnostics it gave me the option to launch windows repair (or start normally) which i did and it sends me back to the same menu I saw upon startup that I described above. When I just click continue startup my desktop loads completely devoid of any functionality, just a default background screen with a useless moveable cursor.

At this point I would be happy to even know how to go about reformatting it to get my laptop back (i don't know if I have the windows disk anymore). Not sure what's happening or what the solution is.

Comment: **Your hard drive is on deaths door you have to buy a new one.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your computer is telling you your hard drive is failing.  You need to replace it ASAP.   If your computer is under warranty, your retailer should accept the SMART failure notice as a warranty replacement.